# How to get Unicode data in JSF's backing bean

Tags: jsf, unicode, javabeans, backing

I have the following code snippets which basically set a hidden field's value to the html content of a div (using jQuery) so I can process it on a backing bean:

### MyPage.xhtml

```
function save_to_hidden()
{
    document.getElementById('hidden_field').value=$('#my_div').html();
}
```

Further down:

```
<h:inputHidden id="hidden_field" value="#{myBean.divData}" />
```

Further down:

```
`<div id="my_div">
   <!-- content in foreign language (spanish) -->
 </div>
```

Further down:

```
<a4j:commandButton value="Save" onclick="save_to_hidden()" action="#{myBean.processDivData}" />
```

I receive the content on the "processDivData" method, but all the "special" characters are replaced with gibberish. Where the problem could be?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The `hidden_field` is rendered as an HTML form element and as such probably encoded the data in the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` MIME type before sending it to the server.

You can use the [URLDecoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLDecoder.html) class to decode these Unicode characters.